# JQuery Appending to the parent, as soon as it's created

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling

I want to use `$(e).append()` as soon as `e` is created.

I know I could use that: `setTimeout(/*func checking if parent exists*/, 100)` But I find that a really bad idea. Is there some kind of a DOM event, that fires when a subtree of a DOM element is modificated?

I would normally just paste it in a source code, to the function which creates the parent, but it's not really possible, partially because I'm actually making a Chrome Extension.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does 'e' is created when all the page is load? If its you can do $(window).load( function() {
  ....
})

Comment: You could use a mutation observer on the parent that everything is being appended to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Grommy No it's created dynamically, depending on ajax result

Comment: So **just** use relevant ajax callback

Comment: It's not really possible, I'm creating a chrome extension and it is a little hard

Comment: if not possible to change source code of ajax request, you could use mutation observer or use global ajax event to filter it out  https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it, but I'll just use the arrive library

Comment: I just checked, this plugin is a wrapper around mutation observer, so ya, it should be fine. As a side note: using CSS animation event: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this library for waiting elements to exist [Arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive)

```
// watch for creation of an element which satisfies the selector ".test-elem"
$(document).arrive(".test-elem", function() {
    // 'this' refers to the newly created element
    var $newElem = $(this);
});

// the above event would watch for creation of element in whole document
// it's better to be more specific whenever possible, for example
$(".container-1").arrive(".test-elem", function() {
    var $newElem = $(this);
});
```

As you can see it's really easy to use. If you do not want to use external library you would need to look into `MutationObserver` in JS since `DOMNodeInserted` is depreciated.

Unbinding the library is easy to as shown in docs:

```
// unbind all arrive events on document element
$(document).unbindArrive();

// unbind all arrive events on document element which are watching for ".test-elem" selector
$(document).unbindArrive(".test-elem");

// unbind only a specific callback
$(document).unbindArrive(callbackFunc);

// unbind only a specific callback on ".test-elem" selector
$(document).unbindArrive(".test-elem", callbackFunc);

// unbind all arrive events
Arrive.unbindAllArrive();
```

Comment: Hmm, that's very interesting, I'll test it in a sec

Comment: I would I was doing something like you are doing now a few years a go this library solved issue and I could move on with project faster instead of messing around with `Mutation Observer` myself. Arrive JS is built on Mutation Observer so you have nice support.

Comment: There is some kind of problem, when I put the code into my chrome extension script it doesn't work, but when I put it in the chrome debugger it works?

Answer (score 0):

If `e` is part of some static HTML then you can use the typical:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code here
}
```

If `e` is added dynamically by your code you can use the `DOMNodeInserted` event. For the sake of this example I assume that `e` is an `<li>`

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function(){
   //code here
});
```